# how to put text in border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert some text in border but don't know how to do.

How can i put some text in middle of border.

Below is the screen-shot it should look like

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Text in Border CSS HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731310/text-in-border-css-html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try HTML legend tag.

[HTML legend](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp)

Answer (score 3):

use  [legend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/legend) inside [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/fieldset)

> The HTML Legend Field Element (`<legend>`) represents a caption for the
>   content of its parent `<fieldset>`.