# To put text on table border as a header

Tags: html, tabular

I have one difficulty. 
I have to put text on table border as a header.
For example:

--------------This Is header-----------------------

Is it possible, if anybody can provide solution on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text in Border CSS HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731310/text-in-border-css-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

You could create a table header, and set the text `position: relative` and move it up a bit. Though, this is not classy.

I would use a fieldset instead, which is 100% valid. You need to give the fieldset a border instead of the table though.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Your text</legend>

    <!-- table goes here -->
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I tried this but failed in some way. Meanwhile I want  rounded corner for this table. How can I achieve this

Comment: hi, Is there is any solution to achieve this with rounded corner? If any other way then provide me?

Comment: Just apply your CSS rules for your border to your fieldset instead of your table... http://www.border-radius.com

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.Its working perfectly now. great Man

Comment: You can mark an answer correct by clicking the "V" left of an answer. It will allow people to find this answer more easily, and people will answer your future questions faster.