# Putting text on a border with css?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make a simple border for a site, in css:

```
    html{
    border-top:3em solid #26282B;

}
```

I would like to have some white text on top of it, how can I do this? I tried making a class, but it always appears under the border.

Comment: can you post you html?

Comment: Do you literally mean to have the text as part of the border? Or do you mean located above the border?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text in Border CSS HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731310/text-in-border-css-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **CAN NOT** make any text in the border. Use `div` or something.

Here is the example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      body{margin:0;padding:0;}
      .someclass {
          width:100%;
          height:3em;
          background-color:#26282B;
          color:white;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='someclass'>
        Sometext Here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your text in a span or div set a class name and using left, top, right, bottom, fix the position like this: 
e.g class="example"

```
.example {
  position:absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Elsewhere this probably help you:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't write something on top of a border - technically yes, but for all purposes here, no, you can't.

So if you want a text on top a short dark background you write something like that:

In yo HTML:

```
<div>My suppa text</div>
```

In yo CSS:

```
div {
  background: #26282B;
  color: #fff;
}
```

`<div>` here being the first element inside your `<body>` it still would have a margin before it, that's because of the browser default style.

You can get rid of it by doing that, in yo CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Now I would suggest you to read about [CSS resets](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #container {
      border: 10px solid;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    #title {
      float: left;
      padding: 0 5px;
      margin: -20px 0 0 30px;
      background: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="title">Border title</div>
    <p>Some content...</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Add this to your style:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
```