# how is the html legend tag displayed in the middle of the border?

Tags: html, fieldset

I'm curious about how the web browser displays the `legend` tags content by inserting the content between a border. If I wanted to recreate this myself I'm thinking I would have to mess with absolute/relative positioning but I think/hope there's a much cleaner way..:P

I inspected the source code but quickly gave up :P

Here's some sample code:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>How did i get here?</legend>
  Name: <input type="text"><br>
  Email: <input type="email">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Does this previous answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731310/text-in-border-css-html

Comment: That's definitely an insightful answer, but it doesn't provide the answers I'm looking for. For example, no matter how much you increase the `font-size` of the `legend` tag, it will come out looking clean and centered. In the above answer however, users are applying guess work on margins and paddings to see if the positioning renders accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I found an amazing tutorial to [*Add A Line Through Your Titles With CSS*](http://www.ryanrudolph.com/add-line-through-your-titles-with-css/)

So I made [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8n8t51dz/)

- The line will always be in the middle of the title, regardless of the size of the text.
- Make sure to give enough space to the `.box` to avoid the text to be too close to the title.
- If you want to give the same look of the `legend`, you can change the `.top_box` class and put `text-align: left;` with some `padding-left`

I hope this answers your question.