# Apply a CSS Properties to HTML Code to Achieve Border and Dashed Line from Image

Tags: html, css

I have a PDF document that I am trying to re-create via HTML. The document is a list of date and events or each season. I am not sure where to apply the border properties to create the inside gradient in the left border and the border radius inside the box.

This is an image of the PDF that I am trying to re-create.

[image: SurforSigEvents]

I have managed to achieve most of it with the following below code.

```css
body {
            width: 1200px;
            font-size: .9335rem
        }
        
        h1 {
            width: 95%;
            margin: .8rem auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            color: #0A3782;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-shadow: 0px 7px 14px #000000;
        }
        
        h1::before,
        h1::after {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 70%;
            margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        
        h1:after {
            margin: 0 -55% 0 .5em;
        }
        
        .ml-250 {
            width: 970px;
            margin: 10px 0px 10px 250px;
            border-left: 75px solid;
            border-top: 15px solid #1c6799;
            border-bottom: 15px solid #0d3251;
            border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
        }
        
        .ml-125 {
            width: 970px;
            margin: 10px 0px 10px 125px;
            border-left: 75px solid;
            border-top: 15px solid #1c6799;
            border-bottom: 15px solid #0d3251;
            border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
        }
        
        #winter {
            display: table;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        
        #winter::before {
            content: "WINTER";
            color: #ffffff;
            display: table-cell;
            transform: translateX(-50px);
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 1.75rem;
            word-break: break-all;
            width: 0.7rem;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: 700;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <h1>2017 Surface Force Significant Events</h1>
    <div id="winter" class="ml-250">
        <div class="w3-row">
            <div class="w3-twothird">
                <table class="">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>01/23/17</td>
                            <td>USS Makin Island Provides Medical Assistance to Pakistani Sailor</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>02/03/17</td>
                            <td>U.S. Japan Successfully Conduct First SM-3 Block IIA Intercept Test</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>02/12/17</td>
                            <td>Navy Christens Future Tulsa</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>03/01/17</td>
                            <td>USS Dewey Fires SM-2 Missile during MISSILEX</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>03/07/17</td>
                            <td>Navy Conducts Successful Missile Test Firing</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>03/07/17</td>
                            <td>“Speed-to-Fleet” Answered the Call: Missiles On-Target “Skin to Skin”</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>03/23/17</td>
                            <td>USS Lake Erie Assists Distressed Mariners</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>03/29/17</td>
                            <td>USS Princeton Participates in Show of Force Strait Transit Exercise</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>03/31/17</td>
                            <td>Ross, Porter Conduct TLAM Strikes into Syria</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-third">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/140x110.jpg" /></td>
                            <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/140x110.jpg" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/140x110.jpg" /></td>
                            <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/140x110.jpg" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the container and pseudos via `position:absolute`/`relative` to draw the dashed borders : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Kyarez

```
.hoz-dash {
  position:relative;/* use it as reference for absolute pseudos */
}
.hoz-dash:before,
.hoz-dash:after{/* generate the pseudos of each containers and set commun styles */
   content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50%;
  border:dashed 3px gray;/* uodate border side, color and thickness to your needs */
}
.hoz-dash:before {
  width:200px;/* give it a width */
}
.hoz-dash:nth-child(even):before {
  width:75px;/* reset width for shorter ones */
}
.hoz-dash:not(:last-of-type):after {/* draw the side but not on the last one */
  height:100%;
}
```

```css
body {
            width: 1200px;
            font-size: .9335rem
        }
        
        h1 {
            width: 95%;
            margin: .8rem auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            color: #0A3782;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-shadow: 0px 14px 28px #000000;
        }
        
        h1::before,
        h1::after {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 70%;
            margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        
        h1:after {
            margin: 0 -55% 0 .5em;
        }
        
        #vert-dash::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            height: 70%;
            margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-left: 1.0px dashed #000000;
        }
        
        .ml-250 {
            width: 970px;
            margin: 10px 0px 10px 250px;
        }
        
        .ml-125 {
            width: 970px;
            margin: 10px 0px 10px 125px;
        }
        
        #winter, #fall,#spring,#summer  {
            display: table;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-left: 75px solid;
            border-top: 15px solid #1c6799;
            border-bottom: 15px solid #0d3251;
            border-radius: 50px 30px 30px 50px;
            -moz-border-radius: 50px 30px 30px 50px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50px 30px 30px 50px;
        }
        
        #winter::before,        
        #spring::before,
        #summer::before,
        #fall::before {
            content: attr(id);
          font-variant:small-caps;
            color: #ffffff;
            display: table-cell;
            transform: translateX(-50px);
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 2rem;
            line-height:1.85rem;
            word-break: break-all;
            width: 2rem;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        
        .lft-pos-10 {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
            left: -10px;
            border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
            -moz-border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
        }
        
        .w3-twothird {
            width: 64.66666%;
        }

.hoz-dash {
  position:relative;
}
.hoz-dash:before,
.hoz-dash:after{
   content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50%;
  border-top:dashed 4px gray;
}
.hoz-dash:before {
  width:200px;
}
.hoz-dash:nth-child(even):before {
  width:75px;
}
.hoz-dash:not(:last-of-type):after {
  height:100%;
  border-top:dashed 0 gray;
  border-left:dashed 4px gray
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>2017 Surface Force Highlights</h1>
    <div id="vert-dash">
        <div class="hoz-dash">
            <div id="winter" class="ml-250">
                <div class="w3-row lft-pos-10">
                    <div class="w3-twothird">
                        <table class="">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>01/23/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Makin Island Provides Medical Assistance to Pakistani Sailor</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>02/03/17</td>
                                    <td>U.S. Japan Successfully Conduct First SM-3 Block IIA Intercept Test</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>02/12/17</td>
                                    <td>Navy Christens Future Tulsa</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/01/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Dewey Fires SM-2 Missile during MISSILEX</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/07/17</td>
                                    <td>Navy Conducts Successful Missile Test Firing</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/07/17</td>
                                    <td>“Speed-to-Fleet” Answered the Call: Missiles On-Target “Skin to Skin”</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/23/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Lake Erie Assists Distressed Mariners</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/29/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Princeton Participates in Show of Force Strait Transit Exercise</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/31/17</td>
                                    <td>Ross, Porter Conduct TLAM Strikes into Syria</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-third">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hoz-dash">
            <div id="spring" class="ml-125">
                <div class="w3-row lft-pos-10">
                    <div class="w3-twothird">
                        <table class="">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>01/23/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Makin Island Provides Medical Assistance to Pakistani Sailor</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>02/03/17</td>
                                    <td>U.S. Japan Successfully Conduct First SM-3 Block IIA Intercept Test</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>02/12/17</td>
                                    <td>Navy Christens Future Tulsa</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/01/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Dewey Fires SM-2 Missile during MISSILEX</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/07/17</td>
                                    <td>Navy Conducts Successful Missile Test Firing</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/07/17</td>
                                    <td>“Speed-to-Fleet” Answered the Call: Missiles On-Target “Skin to Skin”</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/23/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Lake Erie Assists Distressed Mariners</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/29/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Princeton Participates in Show of Force Strait Transit Exercise</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/31/17</td>
                                    <td>Ross, Porter Conduct TLAM Strikes into Syria</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-third">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hoz-dash">
            <div id="summer" class="ml-250">
                <div class="w3-row lft-pos-10">
                    <div class="w3-twothird">
                        <table class="">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>01/23/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Makin Island Provides Medical Assistance to Pakistani Sailor</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>02/03/17</td>
                                    <td>U.S. Japan Successfully Conduct First SM-3 Block IIA Intercept Test</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>02/12/17</td>
                                    <td>Navy Christens Future Tulsa</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/01/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Dewey Fires SM-2 Missile during MISSILEX</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/07/17</td>
                                    <td>Navy Conducts Successful Missile Test Firing</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/07/17</td>
                                    <td>“Speed-to-Fleet” Answered the Call: Missiles On-Target “Skin to Skin”</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/23/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Lake Erie Assists Distressed Mariners</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/29/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Princeton Participates in Show of Force Strait Transit Exercise</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/31/17</td>
                                    <td>Ross, Porter Conduct TLAM Strikes into Syria</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-third">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hoz-dash">
            <div id="fall" class="ml-125">
                <div class="w3-row lft-pos-10">
                    <div class="w3-twothird">
                        <table class="">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>01/23/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Makin Island Provides Medical Assistance to Pakistani Sailor</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>02/03/17</td>
                                    <td>U.S. Japan Successfully Conduct First SM-3 Block IIA Intercept Test</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>02/12/17</td>
                                    <td>Navy Christens Future Tulsa</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/01/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Dewey Fires SM-2 Missile during MISSILEX</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/07/17</td>
                                    <td>Navy Conducts Successful Missile Test Firing</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/07/17</td>
                                    <td>“Speed-to-Fleet” Answered the Call: Missiles On-Target “Skin to Skin”</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/23/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Lake Erie Assists Distressed Mariners</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/29/17</td>
                                    <td>USS Princeton Participates in Show of Force Strait Transit Exercise</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>03/31/17</td>
                                    <td>Ross, Porter Conduct TLAM Strikes into Syria</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-third">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                    <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x130.jpg" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Note**, you can use the comma to separate CSS selectors when the rules to apply are similar. `font-variant` or `font-style` can be used to turn lowercase charactere into uppercase .

Comment: I love you answer! All I need to figure out is the gradient effect for the left border only. Here is an update. https://codepen.io/Khmerboi/pen/dZNQNd

Comment: @TroyPilewski  You can try to lay a gradient hover the boxes  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KyaEKO

Comment: @TroyPilewski By the way, when an answer actually solves your question, it is nice to accept it, so it can be used as a reference for somebody with similar issue and it also tells every potential helper that they can spend time with another question unanswered or unsolved. ... When you think an answer helpfull, you may also upvote it.

Comment: I apologize. I did not know you responded with an update. The gradient you suggested seems like it affects the the white box as well. I only need the colored borders to have the gradient.

Comment: I will try yours when I get to work on Monday and see how it looks, I expect that I will accept then.

Comment: @TroyPilewski okay, then you can use 2 gradients to dispatch only over the borders:  pen updated, https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KyaEKO have fun :)

Comment: The only questions I ask is how do we get the internal radius?