# Create a border with text inside

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a border with the text inside as in the annex. I tried different solutions, but I could not get a solution that would also work on mobile versions.

Does anyone have an idea?

example

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
    
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 200px; /* Might to adjust this based on screen, using css media query */
  margin-top: 30px; /* Might need to play around with this value based on text size */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
</div>
```

Basing it off of this [Text in Border CSS HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731310/text-in-border-css-html), the only problem is having to set the background colour to block out the border, which in your case might not be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I did like this:

```css
#comments h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 147px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
#comments {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 25px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
<h2>Comments</h2>
</div>
```