# How can I place text on an elements border with transparency on the areas where text touches border?

Tags: html, css

[image]

See the image above. I'd like to have the text on top of the border. How can I achieve this using html/css? Are there other alternatives

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border: 4px solid purple;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #FFF;
}

.wrapper p {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum
  </p>
  <a href="">Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57279326/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please look at the answer provided and unlock this question because it may be useful to someone else. The question I've asked is sufficiently different because I needed transparency where the text appears. I'd already seen the other question you claim is a duplicate and the answer provided herein is not the same.

Comment: did you see the link in my previous comment? it shows a solution with transparency exactly the same as the below one which confirm the duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `pseudo elements` of the `h1` tag. In short, you have a wrapper `div` that creates the border left, right and bottom and still then use the pseudo elements of h1 to make the top border.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
  border-top: none;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -41px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 2em;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right:1em;
  margin-left:-50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 5px solid tomato;
}

h1:after {
  margin-right:-50%;
  margin-left:1em;
}

/*Demo Only*/

body{
background:url("https://i.imgur.com/fL3tbdj_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand") no-repeat;

background-size:100% 100%;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
    TITLE HERE
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
    LONGER TITLE HERE
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the position of your h1 to relative, and move It

```
.wrapper p {
  position : relative;
  bottom : 30%;
 }
```

the bottom one means that It will move 30% to the top

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example may be it can give you an idea I found hard to edit your own codes so that's why I made this simple code

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.cont {
  height: 120px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px
}

.cont:before {
  content: "My Header title";
  width: 180px;
  /* border: 1px solid; */
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cont"></div>
```

Comment: This would be perfect only looks like OP wants to have an image background.

Comment: @jbutler483 Precisely, this would work but I wanted the transparency so I could still have visibility on the background image.