Allow text to obscure a div's border but not its background image **without changing the HTML structure**
There is an existing SO post that describes some of the basics of what I need to do: floating text above a border/outline and having that text hide the border/outline. But I have 2 key constraints/ requirements which make that solution non-viable for my case:

I cannot change the HTML structure, which is a <p> within a <div>, so I can't use the same <fieldset> and <legend> trick that works so nicely in the example. (I'm using a framework which lets me change only CSS and the interior content of the <div>.)
The <div> has a photo background, so I can't just put an opaque, single-color background under the text. I'd like for the border to be hidden under the text, but not the background image.

To reiterate the expected result, it should be like this, where the outline is invisible underneath the outline it sits on top of:
----------------------------------
|  ----------------------------  |
|  |                          |  |
|  |                          |  |
|  |                          |  |
|  |                          |  |
|  |                          |  |
|  text-----------------------   |
---------------------------------

In the live example below, the text is easily positioned above the outline by using some basic CSS and an outline-offset to avoid adding a new, inner <div>, but I cannot manage to hide the outline underneath it, even though it has a higher z-index:


.square{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/foto-gratis/arco-iris-al-final-paisaje-carretera_23-2151596720.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.2008272138.1728259200&semt=ais_hybrid");
  background-size: cover;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.square p{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
<div class="square">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>



This would be easy if my background were a solid color I could match, but it's a photo, so I'd need to hide the outline without hiding the photo. I have tried with :before / :after pseudo-elements, but I am unable to make it work. Is this even possible, without modifying the html elements, and with a photo background underneath?
Thanks in advance!

from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77809359/8620333

You can achieve this effect by using a combination of :before and :after pseudo-elements to control where the borders appear. Here’s a solution. Hope this helps.


 .square {
            position: relative;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            /* Adjust this if necessary */
            background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/foto-gratis/arco-iris-al-final-paisaje-carretera_23-2151596720.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.2008272138.1728259200&semt=ais_hybrid");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }

        .square:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            right: 20px;
            bottom: 20px;
            border: 2px solid white;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

        .square p {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            left: 22px;
            margin: 0;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 5px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 100px;
            right: 20px;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            z-index: 1;
        }
   <div class="square">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>




Hi! Thank you for your answer!. I only see 2 problems with your solution. One is that .square::after is not accurate with all kind of text and is only accurate with the example, I mean, if your text change, you will have to change your CSS too or if you have more than one square, it is not useful because you will have to modify the property for each square individually.

And second one, the text is not on the corner as it should be. If you look at the scheme of how it should appear, the text is exactly on the left corner and in this example the text  have the left border before it.

You can use left instead of padding-left and use same background as the div if you want to continue the existing implementation you shared.


.square{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.square p{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: red;
  left: 20px;
}
<div class="square">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>




Well... I forgot to say but the background is an image so I cannot use the same background as a unique color. I also thought about that option but tried to simplify in order to make an example. Sorry!
